# How to combine two table columns into one column in third table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

i have a hive table Android_1 with 6 columns among those 6 columns:

```
android_id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
```

another table ios_2 with 6 columns among those tables:

```
ios_id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
```

now i have table combine which has 5 columns among those 5 columns one column is id and rest are column1,column2, column3,column4.now i want to insert the data into the table combine so that both data in  the Android_id and ios_id should come under id column in table combine and the data in Android_1 in column1,column2,column3,column4 and the data in ios_2 in column1,column2, column3,column4 shoud come under table combine column1,column2, column3,column4

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide expected output. and also please provide sample data and much better also `create table` statements for convenient reproduce and if you really want to receive the answer fast.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a UNION -- like this:

```
SELECT android_id as id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 
FROM android_table

UNION ALL

SELECT ios_id as id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 
FROM ios_table
```